# Template questions, specialization

Tags: c++, c++11

Does anyone know why `template<class T1, class T2> void A<T1, T2, 4>::f0()` fails compilation?  I would think it's a specialization?

Also are these understandings correct?

1. For `// A` the values of the template parameters are used to build an argument list which is used to instantiate the template by defining the class as `class A<A0, ..., An> {}`.
2. For `// B`, when the compiler needs to generate code for `f0()`, it searches template definitions for the class associated with the function.  If a specialized version is found, that is used.  If no specialized version is found, then the non specialized version `A<T1, T2, I>` is chosen in which the template parameters are deduced from the form.

Thanks!

```
// A
template<class T1, class T2, int I>
class A {
public:
    void f0();
};            // primary template

// B
template<class T1, class T2, int I>
void A<T1, T2, I>::f0()
{
    cout << "x" << endl;
}

template<class T1, class T2>
void A<T1, T2, 4>::f0()
{
    cout << "x" << endl;
}

template<>
void A<int, int, 4>::f0()
{
    cout << "z" << endl;
}
```

Compilation:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall test176.cc && ./a.out
test176.cc:17:20: error: nested name specifier 'A<T1, T2, 4>::' for declaration does
      not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization
void A<T1, T2, 4>::f0()
```

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is because [partial template class specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) have to be defined before declaring its functions. In particular, you would have to declare the specialized class before declaring its memeber functions:

```cpp
template<class T1, class T2>
class A<T1,T2,4> {
public:
  void f0();
};
```

It's worth to notice that your last example, `A<int,int,4>::f0()`, is a [(explicit) full class specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) which has different rules as the partial one and that's why that definition does not fail to compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T1, class T2>
void A<T1, T2, 4>::f0()
```

requires specialized definition of:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
class A<T1, T2, 4> {};
```